# Updated from 14.04 to 14.10 and lost Internet access and USB port

Tags: updates, 14.10

I updated to 14.10 from 14.04 without doing a backup first. Now I don't have access to the Internet or my USB port. I have looked everywhere and don't know what to do now.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Note to reviewers: The answer below is great even though the question is (cough, cough). Edited it bit to make it a *bit* acceptable to keep the answer.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I don't have anything saved on my laptop because I keep all docs. on a thumb drive, so it sounds like I can just do a reinstall and I will be fine. Thnx again for your help.

Comment: Klunsford: There is a little grey check-mark below the 1 of this answer, and Mark is going to be much happier if you click that after everything worked out fine, as that means "Yes, the answer is valid".  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**PLAN 1**

This is a primitive approach but it has worked for me.  I used this method again this past month when I mechanically wore out my last computer and it would not turn on. It was really broke.

I bought a HD adapter a few years ago that is good for both ATA and SATA and converts it to USB. It's sort of like a versatile USB enclosure without the box and just the cables.  Every family should have one of these useful devices.  They are very inexpensive and wonderful to have around.  It'll take a week to get it from Amazon.

Take out your HD.  Attach your HD through the cabling to another Ubuntu computer (same formatting). Then take all your data off the HD.  Since my last computer was toast, I had already bought a new computer and just transferred the data directly onto my new computer.  You will need an intermediate storage place for your data somewhere because you will be putting the HD back into your computer.

Put the HD back in your computer and re-install 14.10 on your computer. I'm betting it will be fine with a fresh install. Then take the data from the intermediate storage and move it back onto your computer.  If you have always wanted a larger HD on your computer, this would be a good time to order a new one because you are already re-installing 14.10.  Then you could actually buy a USB enclosure for your old drive and use it for data backup storage.

Even if some smart guy rescues your 14.10 installation and USB port you can't go wrong by getting one of these handy devices.

**PLAN 2**
Make an Ubuntu 14.10 USB Ubuntu boot disk.  I use Unetbootin.  Boot it through the BIOS and use it as a LiveCD USB.  They call it a "trial usage without install" or something like that.  This will give you basically a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.10 and your WiFi and USB ports should work fine.  Use this LiveCD to rescue your data onto an external device of some sort, ideally a HD in a USB case.  After you have taken the data off, continue with the LiveCD and use it to install 14.10.  Then move your data back.  This is a nice trick.

You could also take the time to make the USB disk a "persistent" install.  This means the install will remember what you have done to it and write changes to the USB disk.  A normal install disk only keeps it in memory and it is gone when you pull it out.  Now you have a usable version of Ubnutu 14.10 on a jump drive.  Keep it on your keychain sort of like a Swiss Army Knife.  You can get yourself out of tight spots with an "OS on a stick".

You can also have a personalized OS to use when you are on the move and boot into your own little Ubuntu version / desktop when you are out and about.  It runs a bit slow because of the slow speed of most user grade SD cards and of USB 2.0 ports but it works.  They say you should use at least a 4-8Gb for a "persistent" install whereas you need a minimum of only 2G for just an install disk.  In fact, if you used a large enough SD card you could download your data right onto the persistent disk and use that for intermediate storage.