# ubuntu 14.04 recovery mode, help

Tags: boot

My laptop wouldn't boot so I looked up online things I can do. I'm stuck under the GRUB area at recovery mode as I don't know which Ubuntu with Linux...... generic (recovery mode) to chose. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Use the top or first recovery mode you come to in Grub and then see what happens.  Maybe you will be lucky and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery mode very well may work. If not, you may have a problem that extends beyond the boot process and we will need more information to help. Good luck!

Comment: I'll have a go at it tonight after work and if it doesn't work I'll get back to both of you with more information.

Comment: recovery mode won't work unfortunately. the screen just keeps going over and over with the numbers and words from recovery mode. the only things I can read quick enough are:  UDMA/133: configured, unable to read itable block, sense key: medium error, failed: read DMA EMT. I don't even understand any of this, so any help right now would be wonderful. I keep episodes from tv shows, movies, pictures and documents and I don't have a copy of about half of it.

Answer (score 0):

Something is corrupted.  It would be hard to figure out what is causing the problem.  I'd say you should do a clean install again. Presumably you know how to do this.  Maybe you want the long term version 14.04. Basically you have non-functional operating system with your data on the computer.  If you could recover your data you would be fine.

You are in the same situation as the fellow who recently asked a similar question with his data on his computer. You can read my answer.  Pose some questions if you don't follow how this works.  Use the second plan as it is hard to rescue a HD out of a notebook.

[Updated from 14.04 to 14.10 and lost Internet access and USB port](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572231/updated-from-14-04-to-14-10-and-lost-internet-access-and-usb-port/572607#572607)